# Laravel: How to do Inverse HasManyThrough?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have three tables. I want to display all data from *cms_planner* table together with *Topic Name* from *cms_topic* table. To achieve that, I need to go through the *cms_subject* table.

I want to use *belongsToMany* but I already have *cms_subject* table that holds the foreign key for *cms_planner* and the foreign key for *cms_topic*. The table name does not represent *pivot key*.

I also want to use *hasManyThrough* but it doesn't work. I'm thinking to inverse the *hasManyThrough*.

How can I achieve that?

**1. CmsPlanner**
i. planner_id
ii. subject_id
iii. date_start

**2. CmsSubject**
i. subject_id
ii. topic_id

**3. CmsTopic**
i. topic_id
ii. topic name

In CmsPlanner model

```
public function subject(){
  return $this->hasManyThrough(
    'App\CmsTopic',
    'App\CmsSubject',
    'topic_id', 'topic_id', 'planner_id');}
```

In CmsPlanner controller

```
CmsPlanner::with('subject')->get();
```

Comment: What exaclty does not work on the HasManyTrough , because it is what you are looking for https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: @Christophvh the HasManyThrough should be declared in _cms_planner_ model, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this relation on CmsSubject

```
public function cmsTopic()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CmsTopic', 'topic_id', 'topic_id');
}
```

then add following relation on CmsPlanner

```
public function cmsSubject()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CmsSubject', 'subject_id', 'subject_id');
}
```

to get data

```
$cms_planner = CmsPlanner::with('CmsSubject')->where('id', $planner_id)->get();

'user' => $this->business->user
```